# Inverse Matrices. Unsure how to solve it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Find the inverse of matrix $A$. Can some please show me how to do this question.I've been attempting this question for quite awhile now, although don't know how to proceed.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{2}{5} \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{10}\\ \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{10}   
\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: What do you think -- how do we normally find an inverse matrix?

Comment: Normally you would use the inverse algorithm which is to have one side already row reduced and you attempt to swap them.

Comment: @Math1000 thankyou so much for changing this up for me. Couldnt figure out how to do it.

Comment: So you do elementary row operations on the augmented matrix $[ A \mid I ]$.  Is that what you did?  If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: So my first step was to remove the fractions by multiplying the matrix by 10. Although I'm not sure on how to proceed after this. Also yes those were my intentions although Im just confused with this as it is in the fraction form.

Comment: OK.  I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Simplify your life by inverting $B=10A$ instead. Then $A^{-1} = 10 B^{-1}$.

Comment: @copper.hat yes thats what i meant in my previous comment. Although I didnt know what to do with the 10 while row reducing.

Comment: I am computationally incompetent, so will use any simplifying trick.

Comment: I just multiplied the fractions out of each row first step.  I don't think that's any harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}} & \color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}} & \color{blue}{-\frac{2}{5}}& \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 \\ \color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}} & \color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}} & \color{blue}{\frac{1}{10}} & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0\\ \color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}} & \color{blue}{-\frac{4}{5}} & \color{blue}{\frac{1}{10}} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1}   
\end{array}\right] &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{5} & 0 & 0 \\ \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{1} & 0 & \color{blue}{10} & 0\\ \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{-8} & \color{blue}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{10}   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_1 \to 5R_1 \\ R_2 \to 10R_2 \\ R_3 \to 10R_3\end{pmatrix}\\ &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{5} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{-10} & \color{blue}{10} & 0\\ 0 & \color{blue}{-10} & \color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{-10} & 0 & \color{blue}{10}   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_2 \to R_2-2R_1 \\ R_3 \to R_3-2R_1\end{pmatrix} \\ &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{5} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{-10} & \color{blue}{10} & 0\\ 0 & \color{blue}{-10} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-10} & \color{blue}{10}   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_3 \to R_3 - R_2\end{pmatrix} \\ &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{5} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{2} & 0\\ 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-1}   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_2 \to \frac 15R_2 \\ R_3 \to -\frac 1{10}R_3\end{pmatrix} \\ &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{1} \\ 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{2} & 0\\ 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-1}   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_1 \to R_1+2R_2-R_3\end{pmatrix} \\ &\sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{1} \\ 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-1} \\ 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{2} & 0   
\end{array}\right] & \begin{pmatrix}R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

So the inverse matrix is $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ -2 & 2 & 0   
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: on the answers the column 2 is 3,1,2

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Fixed.

Comment: hey if its not to much of a bother, could you write the steps of the matrices?

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Better?

Comment: Much better, thankyou so much. The problems with row reducing I always have is that most of the time the numbers get too big while row reducing which therefore tells me  I did something wrong, and then annoys me to do it all over again.